# Is it possible to set some value to the element in `postLink` function in `compile` of `directive` in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The doc of angularjs:

```
myModule.directive('directiveName', function factory(injectables) {
  var directiveDefinitionObject = {
    priority: 0,
    template: '<div></div>',
    templateUrl: 'directive.html',
    replace: false,
    transclude: false,
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: false,
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      return {
        pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... },
        post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                         // ????
                         // is it possible to set the content of iElement?
                    }
      }
    }
  };
  return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```

In the `postLink` function inside `compile`, is it possible to set some text to the `iElement`?

I've tried:

```
iElement.html("some");
iElement.textContent = "some";
jQuery(iElement).html("some");
```

But it seems none of them worked.

Comment: I believe your problem is not on the directive itself. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/vjnN7/ . The `iElement.html("some")` works as expected...

Comment: You are right, I just found removed that element before linking :(

Comment: Freewind, consider deleting this question, or have @bmleite answer it and then accept the answer.  Either way, it will be helpful to get this question off the "unanswered" list.

Comment: @bmleite, please make your comment as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iElement.html("some");` should work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/vjnN7/

```
app.directive('someDirective', function() {
  return {
    priority: 0,
    template: '<div>Test...</div>',    
    replace: false,
    transclude: false,
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: false,
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      return {
        pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {  },
        post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                iElement.html('Some other test...');                         
             }
      }
    }
  };  
});
```